# after update Ubuntu to 16.04 and re-install mysql 5.7, FF-browser doesn't display any query results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

**problem is:** after re-install mysql 5.7, FF-browser and Chrome-browser doesn't display any query results. I tested with standart querys from mysql-manual:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "cydb4tsa", "RedGround");
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    echo "Table myCity successfully created.";
}
```

**please understand:** i'm not an administrator, not used to handle such problems every day.
My project is in serious threat, because I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 with mysql-server-5.7, result after all is that no query result is displayed in FF-browser or Chrome ... I miss feedback on my call for help (I included step by step report of the problem) in 'ask Ubuntu'.
i tried analyzing mysql_errors:
    cat error.log | grep 'Warning'

```
sebu@sebu-Inspiron-3437:/var/log/mysql$ cat error.log | grep 'Warning'
2017-01-20T03:25:22.334192Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-01-20T03:25:22.334288Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-01-20T03:25:22.650055Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-20T03:25:25.671903Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-01-20T22:29:11.912552Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-01-20T22:29:11.912644Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-01-20T22:29:12.294907Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-20T22:29:15.527007Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-01-20T22:35:01.057707Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-01-20T22:35:01.057815Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-01-20T22:35:03.952763Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-20T22:35:10.096231Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key

/var/log/mysql# ulimit -n 5000
```

also done:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL table_open_cache = 2000;
```

no effect and varables went back to old value after reboot

**i can provide some more info now:**
i search for updates for Ubuntu 16.04 and following happened:
[image: new updates for mysql available]

after install
[image]
[image]

report was sent
**yes** i modified link-source from mysql.cnf but i disable this modifications because they caused an error-msg.
please release this report from hold status, or give me info where is the right place for this topic!

**after the newest update** even the command-line function cause an error-msg, 
befor this part was working normaly.
~$ mysql -u root -pcydb4tsa RedGround

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

note) After updating Ubuntu again (new ubuntu kernel) the command line mysql>  run without error. The newerly update finished successfully, but i still get an empty screen on my web-browser after running test scripts :-(

**maybe good to know:**
phpMyAdmin works without any problems. **Why and How phpMyAdmin** can properly connect my DB ????

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking. Try doing two things: First, write a short sentence that is your *main problem*. That's your title. Next, explain what you're trying to do and what's actually happening, with a [mcve] if relevant, in the body of your question.

Comment: perhaps you upgraded php to 7 at the same time and are using the legacy mysql_* API?

Comment: problem is: after install mysql 5.7 browser doesn't display query results
i tested with standart querys from mysql-manual: $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "cydb4tsa", "RedGround");  if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    echo "Table myCity successfully created.";
}

Comment: ok add some error checking and see what that says

Comment: you are right, also PHP was updated to vers 7, I add error-log to my original post

Comment: you can see my post on ubuntu:http://askubuntu.com/questions/873782/php-problem-after-install-mysql-5-7-browser-doesnt-display-query-results

Comment: you need to edit the mysql.in file with those changes if you want then to "stick" after a reboot.